# Trouble move-capturing std::unique_ptr in a lambda using std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr

I'd like to capture a variable of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>` in a lambda expression (in other words, "capture by move"). I found a solution which uses std::bind to capture unique_ptr (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744730/2478832) and decided to use it as a starting point. However, the most simplified version of the proposed code I could get doesn't compile (lots of template mistakes, it seems to try to call unique_ptr's copy constructor).

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

std::function<void ()> a(std::unique_ptr<int>&& param)
{
    return std::bind( [] (int* p) {},
        std::move(param));
}

int main()
{
    a(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int()));
}
```

Can anybody point out what is wrong with this code?

EDIT: tried changing the lambda to take a reference to unique_ptr, it still doesn't compile.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

std::function<void ()> a(std::unique_ptr<int>&& param)
{
    return std::bind( [] (std::unique_ptr<int>& p) {}, // also as a const reference
        std::move(param));
}

int main()
{
    a(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int()));
}
```

Here's Visual Studio 2012 output:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\tuple(151): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1447) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\tuple(521) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tuple_val<_This>::_Tuple_val<const _Ty&>(_Other)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _This=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>  ,            _Other=const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\tuple(521) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tuple_val<_This>::_Tuple_val<const _Ty&>(_Other)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _This=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>  ,            _Other=const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\tuple(521) : while compiling class template member function 'std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::tuple(const std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(1152) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::tuple(const std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(1152) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(15) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Bind<false,void,a::<lambda_2ad08ede4c4ce9c02d5497417b633d1d>,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
```

Comment: You've to write `[] (std::unique_ptr<int> && p) {}` instead of `[] (int* p) {}`

Comment: @Nawaz: No, not really. Actually neither the lambda nor `a` should take the `std::unique_ptr` through an rvalue-reference

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Why?

Comment: @Nawaz: You should only use `&&` when you need to differentiate between lvalue and rvalue. This is not the case here, and there is no reason not to take the argument to `a` by reference: by-value suffices. The case of the lambda is different, in this case the signature is saying that the argument to the lambda is a temporary from which you can freely move and destroy the original, but the fact is that it is *not* a temporary, it is a `std::unique_ptr` that lives inside the bound object. If you move out of it, subsequent calls to the `std::function<void()>` will cause a call with null.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: thanks for the subtleties. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: I imagine we are going to see far more rvalue-references than make sense. But that is what happens when you have a cool new feature. If you find an rvalue-reference outside of a constructor/assignment, think twice whether it is needed or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the version that passes a lambda taking `unique_ptr` by reference to `std::bind` is your conversion to `std::function` - `std::function` requires functions to be CopyConstructible ([func.wrap.func.con] p7). Try it without the `std::function` ([Live at ideone](http://ideone.com/rD9zaA)):

```
auto f = std::bind([](std::unique_ptr<int>&){},
                   std::make_unique<int>());
```

Answer (score 4):

The second argument to `bind` will be passed to the bound object at the time of call. The problem is that the lambda takes a `int*`, but the argument is a `std::unique_ptr<int>` and there is no conversion from the latter to the former.

It should compile (untested) if you change the signature of the lambda to take a `std::unique_ptr` by reference/const-reference

Comment: I've tried that also, and it doesn't compile. I'm testing it through ideone.com (they've got gcc 4.7.2). I've also tried Visual Studio 2012 (November CTP), with the same results.

Comment: @user2478832: Can you post the link to IDEONE?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the internals of `std::bind` is that it will always make a copy of the 1st argument object that is being bound to the function-object rather than moving it (even if that argument is an rvalue), so you'll always end up with a call to the copy-constructor for whatever object you are attempting to bind to the function object, and not the move-constructor, even with the use of `std::move`.